# Cannot install Ubuntu in any way

Tags: boot, system-installation

My CPU is Core i7-3770 and my motherboard is Asus Maximus thing as the picture says. My GPU is AMD Firepro w7100. This error message appears when I select *Install Ubuntu*.

[image]

I downloaded Ubuntu iso file and put it into my USB with Rufus. Then I booted to USB and tried to install Ubuntu. When I plugged the USB flash drive into the normal USB slot, and then I selected *Install Ubuntu* in grub, nothing but a static black screen was shown. When I plugged it into a USB 3.0 slot and did the same thing, these messages appeared and no further progress beyond that was shown. It said `Rebooting in 30 seconds`, but it didn't even reboot by itself. I tried with different a USB flash drive, and tried changing the USB creator program to Universal USB Installer, but it still didn't work.I reformatted the USB many times, but the results were always the same.

I successfully installed Ubuntu in the past on the same PC, but now I can't install it. I tried installing with all 20.04 and 18.04 and 16.04 versions. None of them worked. The most frequent results were just a black screen. Even 'safe graphics' mode did not work. It said `VGACON disables amdgpu.` when I selected safe graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the problem is with the video output. It must be going through Intel onboard graphics by default instead of your gpu. If your monitor is plugged into the gpu try plugging into the onboard graphics instead. It's located directly on the motherboard I/O. I hope that helps.